# NSTask Undecalared!

Tags: iphone, class

i am integrating ASIHTTPRequest in  my app and included some supported frameworks found in XCode but in one file of this API i am getting an error "NSTask undeclared" in this declaration...
NSTask *task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
any suggestions??

Thanks...

Comment: `If you create an NSTask object in this manner, you must be sure to set the executable name using setLaunchPath:. If you don’t, an NSInvalidArgumentException is raised.`

Answer (score 5):

`NSTask` is not available on iOS. It looks like you’ve inadvertently included some files from ASIHTTPRequest that are meant for Mac OS X only. Remove those files from your project — from what I see, only Classes/Tests/ASIDataCompressorTests.m uses `NSTask` — and the ‘NSTask undeclared’ error shouldn’t happen again.